# Can CanonicalUser be used with an STS assume role policy?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-iam

I am trying to provide a cross account access (using Terraform) to another AWS account using the canonical ID provided by them. Can Canonical User Id be used to assume role in my account or is it something that can be used with a bucket ACL?

Comment: Did you mix with [IAM Unique ID](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_identifiers.html#identifiers-unique-ids)?

Comment: If it is iam unique ID, yes, you can, in policy, replace IAM ARN with its unique id directly

Comment: This is canonical ID, not the IAM unique ID. IfI had the arn, it would have been strightforward, but all I got is the canonical ID.

Comment: did you try to replace the arn with canonical ID? will you get expect result? should work directly. If not, paste the code to us for reference.